# Error:(25, 94) error: incompatible types: SettingsFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import static android.R.attr.fragment;

public class AppPreferences extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_detail);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
       // fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment, "SETTING_FRAGMENT");
```

the error starting here is settingsFragment and the error is Error:(25, 94) error: incompatible types: SettingsFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

```
FragmentTransaction setting_fragment = fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment, "SETTING_FRAGMENT");
setting_fragment.commit();
```

and this is my settingsFragment

```
public  static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing android.R.id.content to R.id.content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use (if you want to keep the compatibility)  the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` included in the support v7 compatibility library.

`PreferenceFragment` is not included in the compatibility set of fragments, so changing `PreferenceFragment` to `PreferenceFragmentCompat` should suffice for your porpuses.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html?utm_campaign=ADP-protip-827&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=plus&linkId=16598687) out.

Hope it helps

Comment: Same error? Any difference? @ThetruesAbdallah update the question with your changes

Comment: `<code> public static class  SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences);


        }</code>` the error now is cannot resolve PreferenceFragmentCompat

Answer (score 2):

hey i got the solution to my problem

public class AppPreferences extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_detail);
```

The problem was with this code here so and this  `getSupportFragment();`  so i use just  `getFragmentManager();` and its works

     `// FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
      //  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();`

```
    SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction setting_fragment;
    setting_fragment = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment, "SETTING_FRAGMENT");
    setting_fragment.commit();


}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: I had the same problem. I have tried to use "PreferenceFragmentCompat", as indicated in the accepted answer, but I didn't succeed to configure the theme. Then I have replaced  getSupportFragmentManager() by getFragmentManager() and it worked fine.